# Coding the Cox-deBoor algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, iteration

The most common way to calculate the b-spline basis functions is to use the infamous [Cox-deBoor algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor%27s_algorithm) (which many people take as a definition which it isn't)

My code so far is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double b_spline(int i, int j, double x, double u[]) {

double bs;
double a,b,c,d,e,f;
int k=1;
while (x>u[k])tions
    {
        k=k+1;
}
if (j==0)
    if (x>=u[i] && x<=u[i+1]) bs=1;
    else bs=0;
else
    a=x-u[i]; b=u[i+j-1]-u[i];
    c=u[i+j]-x;d=u[i+j]-u[i+1];
    cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << " a/b=" << a/b << " i=" <<i << " j=" << j << endl;
    cout << "c=" << c << " d=" << d << " c/d=" << c/d << endl;
    if (b==0)
    {
        e=0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        e=(x-u[i])/(u[i+j-1]-u[i]);
    }

    if (d==0)
    {
        f=0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        f=(u[i+j]-x)/(u[i+j]-u[i+1]);
    }
bs=e*b_spline(i,j-1,x,u)+f*b_spline(i+1,j-1,x,u);
return bs;
}

int main() {

    double u[11]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
    cout << "The value of p(0.4) is " << b_spline(4,3,0.4,u);
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Now it seems to begin to work okay but all of a sudden one of my values goes haywire. I think I have trapped everything (obviously I haven't) Can you say at first blush what is going on?

I am new to C++ and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: There is probably a mistake in the first if-else statement (the one right after the `while`). If you don't use the curly braces then **only** the first statements after the `if` and `else` are conditionally executed. But your indentation suggests that your `else` part is much more than just the `a=x-u[i];`. It is best practice to **always** use curly braces. It will spare you some headbanging against the wall (or keyboard).

Comment: Hi MatthewHunt and welcome to Stack Overflow! Normally we don't sign the post with our name, your image avatar does the same thing. Additionally, if you tag your question with the language you are using (like C++), you get your code auto-highlighted. Personally, I've never heard of this algorithm, so your question might be more useful if you link a reference, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor%27s_algorithm.

Comment: Typo/paste error?  `while (x>u[k])tions`?

Comment: @JanŽegklitz: Good catch. if everything up to the `return` were part of the else clause, each branch would have one assignment to `bs`. That makes sense.